# A proof of $\dim(R[T])=\dim(R)+1$ without prime ideals?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, krull-dimension

**Please read this first before answering.** This question is only concerned with a proof of the dimension formula using the Coquand-Lombardi characterization below. If you post something that doesn't mention the characterization, then it's not an answer and is offtopic.

---

**Background.** If $R$ is a commutative ring, it is easy to prove $\dim(R[T]) \geq \dim(R)+1$, where $\dim$ denotes the Krull dimension. If $R$ is Noetherian, we have equality. Every proof I'm aware of uses quite a bit of commutative algebra and non-trivial theorems such as Krull's intersection theorem.

T. Coquand and H. Lombardi have found a surprisingly elementary characterization of the Krull dimension that does not use prime ideals at all.

> T. Coquand, H. Lombardi, **A Short Proof for the Krull Dimension of a Polynomial Ring**, The American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 112, No. 9 (Nov., 2005), pp. 826-829 (4 pages)

You can read the article [here](http://hlombardi.free.fr/publis/KrullMathMonth.pdf).

For $x \in R$ let $R_{\{x\}}$ be the localization of $R$ at the multiplicative subset $x^{\mathbb{N}} (1+xR) \subseteq R$. Then we have

$$\qquad \dim(R) = \sup_{x \in R} \left(\dim(R_{\{x\}})+1\right)\!. \label{1}\tag{$\ast$}$$

It follows that for $k \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $\dim(R) \leq k$ if and only if for all $x_0,\dotsc,x_k \in R$ there are $a_0,\dotsc,a_k \in R$ and $m_0,\ldots,m_k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$x_0^{m_0} (\cdots ( x_k^{m_k} (1+a_k x_k)+\cdots)+a_0 x_0)=0.$$
You can use this to *define* the Krull dimension.

A consequence of this is a new short proof of $\dim(K[x_1,\dotsc,x_n])=n$, where $K$ is a field. Using Noether normalization and the fact that integral extensions don't change the dimension, it follows that $\dim(R\otimes_K S)=\dim(R)+\dim(S)$ if $R,S$ are finitely generated commutative $K$-algebras. In particular $\dim(R[T])=\dim(R)+1$. This could be useful for introductory courses on algebraic geometry which don't want to waste too much time with dimension theory.

> **Question.** Can we use the characterization \eqref{1} of the Krull dimension by Coquand-Lombardi above to prove $\dim(R[T])=\dim(R)+1$ for Noetherian commutative rings $R$?

Such a proof should not use the prime ideal characterization/definition of the Krull dimension. Notice that the claim is equivalent to $\dim(R[T]_{\{f\}}) \leq \dim(R)$ for all $f \in R[T]$.

Maybe this question is a bit naïve. I suspect that this can only work if we find a first-order property of rings which is satisfied by Noetherian rings and prove the formula for these rings. Notice that in contrast to that the [Gelfand-Kirillov dimension](http://ysharifi.wordpress.com/2011/04/26/gk-dimension-of-polynomial-rings/) satisfies $\mathrm{GK}\dim(R[T])=\mathrm{GK}\dim(R)+1$ for every $K$-algebra $R$.

Comment: Note: I've asked this on stackexchange http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/358423 and was encouraged to ask this here.

Comment: Another note: The characterization by T. Coquand and H. Lombardi is correct :-).

Comment: Yes, the statement is correct without any assumptions (I was mistaken). But still, it does not follow from what you can find in this article, which was the point.

Comment: I mean, the whole purpose was not to waste too much time with dimension theory. But this way you have to prove  Corollary first, and it takes a little more then meets the eye.

Comment: @Alex: When you claim that the paper has a huge gap, you should say exactly(!) what is wrong.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: The alleged counterexample of Alex was puzzling. What was wrong finally?

Comment: @ACL: $\dim(C(S^1))>0$ since there are functions $f$ with $f^2 \nmid f$. (Unfortunately Alex deleted his example. My comments contained more elaborate explanations as well as references.)

Comment: @ACL: The example was interesting, but wrong: this ring has a positive Krull dimension. The problem is, there are nonclosed prime ideals whose closure is a maximal ideal. So, it makes a difference whether you take it for a Banach algebra or for an abstract algebra. In fact, the statement of Corollary is correct, it is the proof which is not.

Comment: I would like to know more generally what happens if you take the Coquand-Lombardi characterization as a definition and try to develop the basics of dimension theory from there.

Comment: @Alex: Please consider double-checking your claims concerning counterexamples, gaps and incomplete proofs. Especially in answers which don't address the question at all.

Comment: @Neil Strickland: This is an interesting question, but I do not think anybody can answer it, before someone tried to do this.

Comment: @Martin Brandenburg: Well, I was wrong again. Sorry about bothering you. Anyway, I think you asked a good question. I upvoted it.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: are there known non-Noetherian examples where $\text{dim}(R[T])>\text{dim}(R)+1$?

Comment: @NeilStrickland: The following example can be found in Hutchins, *Examples of Commutative Rings*, Example 27: Let $k$ be a field and let $R = k(y)[[x]] \times_{k(y)} k$ the ring of those power series in $x$ with coefficients in $k(y)$ resp. $k$ for the constant term. Then $\dim(R)=1$ and $\dim(R[T])=3$. I've also read that actually every number between $\dim(R)+1$ and $2 \dim(R)+1$ may appear as $\dim(R[T])$.

Comment: @Neil: What Martin read (every number between the bound appers) you can also read, namely in A. Seidenberg, _On the dimension theory of rings (II),_ Pacific J. Math. 4 (1954), 603-614.

Comment: Anything wrong with the fact that all polynomials over the trivial ring are 0? IMHO 1 ≠ 0 must be required explicitly.

Comment: The elementary characterization is also very useful in a topos-internal context. For example, a scheme $X$ is of dimension $\leq n$ if and only if, from the internal perspective of the little Zariski topos $\mathrm{Sh}(X)$, the (then plain old) ring $\mathcal{O}_X$ is of Krull dimension $\leq n$. See Proposition 3.13 of [these sketchy notes](https://github.com/iblech/internal-methods/blob/master/notes.pdf?raw=true).

Comment: @Ingo: Thank you, this is one more piece of motivation to read your notes! (I've already started.)

Comment: Can some moderator make this question CW, please?

Comment: @IngoBlechschmidt Let me ask a philosophical question about your characterization. It seems to me that the Krull dimension is a pure topological invariant, namely, completely determined by the Zariski locale (or topos), so the datum of the structure sheaf seems to be redundant?

Comment: Coquand--Lombardi is constructive. Do you assume the axiom of choice for the "elementary" proof you want?

Comment: Axiom of choice and LEM are OK for me. I just would like to know if there is a proof which doesn't take the detour with prime ideals and non-trivial results from commutative algebra, and instead uses the Coquand-Lombardi characterization.

Comment: Let me mention that, in the book by Lombardi–Quitté (available on [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.02942)), §XIII.8, they showed (constructively) that the *valuative dimension* $\dim_vR[T]$ is $1+\dim_vR$, and if the Krull dimension and the valuative dimension agree for $R$, then they also agree for $R[T]$.

Comment: @Z.M I think you are right; however, I still wanted to find internal characterization of dimension, in order to be able to carry out as much work as possible internally to the (little or big) Zariski topos.

Comment: @IngoBlechschmidt Is the homotopy dimension of a topos internal? I am also slightly skeptical about the moral correctness of Zariski toplogy, instead of its Hochster dual. Compare with [Lombarbi–Mahboubi, Valuative lattices and spectra](https://arxiv.org/abs/2210.16558) §3.1.

Comment: Seven answers, all deleted.

Comment: I am not sure why people are editing my question without actually improving it, it seems they just want to apply their way of writing. I have rolled back two times now. Please leave the question as it is.

Comment: @MartinBrandenbug.  But you accepted my edit of your intro verbatim.  Previously, you said much more, like "This is not the place to advertise your favorite..." and "will probably be deleted by moderators."  And then everyone's answers miraculously get flagged for deletion.  It came across as browbeating.  How are you to know what moderators will probably do?

Comment: @JesseElliott They don't get "miraculously" flagged. Some people (myself included) voted to delete answers that insisted on addressing the question they wished Martin had asked, and then doubling down when Martin said "that's not what I'm looking for".

Comment: @JesseElliott I checked, and yours is actually the only deleted answer that avoids using prime ideals. 3 are nonsense/spam, 2 give variants of the standard proof using prime ideals, 1 is a comment too long to fit in the comment box that turned out to contain a mistake and was probably deleted for that reason.